# Shimano GRX 2x11 brake rotor compatibility

Tags: shimano, disc-brake, gravel

I am looking for possible disc rotors for the GRX 2x11 that comes with the GRX BR-RX810 brakes but can just find one recommendation which are the Shimano Ultegra SM-RT800 Center Lock Ice-Tech, that I find very ugly. 
Even on the Shimano page I cannot find anything else. Are there any other rotors that are compatible with the GRX BR-RX810 and GRX2x11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with Shimano, the [line-up charts for the GRX groups](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc/rx810/DI2_2x11) suggest an SM-RT64, SM-RT70 and RT-MT800 for use with RX400 and RX600 and RX810 groups respectively. None of those discs have the 'bladed' look of the SM-RT800 rotor.

Answer (score 11):

In all honesty, you can use any disc you like, and from practically any manufacturer as long as the dia. (and fitment type) is the same.

Comment: There are some limitations, however.  I had purchased some "pretty" Hope 2 piece rotors that had red anodized centers that cost me a pretty penny.  They did not work even though they were the right size because they had rivets holding the outer rotor to the rotor center and the rivets stuck-out too far and hit the brake caliper.  So just be careful when ordering a non Shimano part... make sure you can return whatever you buy if it doesn't fit!

Comment: Just to chime in, I have had a similar experience with higher end rotors with aluminum centers.

Comment: It's always that problem with any 'exotic' components that some are not compatible, mainly because they don't follow the exact specifications.